# SQL: Update Table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have got 3 tables: Event, task, task_handler.

```
EVENT:
event_id|name

TASK_HANDLER:
event_id|task_seq|handler

TASK:
event_id|task_seq|script
```

what i want is that "script" has the same content as "name".
task_handler.handler is event.event_id.

So what i have to do is get the event.name for each event_id/task_seq combination an put it into task.script.

Result should like this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/stackover.jpg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your relationships (I'm confused by handler being the event_id) but try this:

```
UPDATE `TASK` t
INNER JOIN `TASK_HANDLER` th ON th.event_id = t.event_id AND th.task_seq = t.task_seq
INNER JOIN `EVENT` e ON e.event_id = th.handler
SET t.script = e.name
```

Comment: thank you, thats it :) every event can be a handler of another event .. thats why this relationship is here

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
SELECT
  e.event_id,t.task_seq,a.name as 'script'
FROM
  EVENT e, TASK_HANDLER t
WHERE
  e.event_id = t.event_id
```